# SQL Server 2008 equivalent of "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING"

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have this query for my DB

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        r.CustomerID,
        r.DateReceived,
        r.Point,
        mr.MaxPoint,
        COALESCE(SUM(r.Point) OVER (PARTITION BY r.CustomerID ORDER BY r.DateReceived
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS cumPoints
    FROM Rewards r
    INNER JOIN MaxRewards mr ON r.CustomerID = mr.CustomerID
)

SELECT
    CustomerID,
    DateReceived,
    CASE WHEN cumPoints + Point < MaxPoint
         THEN Point
         ELSE CASE WHEN MaxPoint - cumPoints > 0
                   THEN MaxPoint - cumPoints ELSE 0 END END AS Point
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    CustomerID,
    DateReceived;
```

When I deployed this to another machine which is still using SQL 2008, the query `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` is not working, anyone know the equivalent of this syntax for SQL 2008?

Comment: Side note: 2008 version (as well as 2008 R2) is out of extended support for about a year now. It's high time to consider an upgrage.

Comment: Agree with the above.  It's time to upgrade.  2008 probably isn't even supported anymore, which means it could be a security risk.

Comment: I wish I could haha

Comment: @warheat1990 it's not haha at all. 2008 has reached End-Of-Life. The earliest version in mainstream support is 2016. Given the difference in both hardware and software these past 12 years, you could probably use SQL Server Express to handle the same load.

Comment: @warheat1990 if you can't upgrade, you'll have to redesign the entire query and quite probably the database, to get adequate performance. The windowing functions allowed calculating running totals without requiring multiple table scans and storing intermediate results. If you search SO for your actual problem (calculating running totals) you'll find several answers, eg `(select sum(c.Points) from Rewards c where c.Customer ID=r.CustomeriD and c.DateReceived<r.DateReceived) - r.Points`. Needless to say, this has to run the subquery for every outer row

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely upgrade your SQL Server.  In the meantime, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT r.CustomerID, r.DateReceived, r.Point, mr.MaxPoint,
       (SELECT SUM(r2.Point)
        FROM rewards r2
        WHERE r2.CustomerId = r.CustomerId AND
              r2.DateReceived < r.DateReceived
       ) AS cumPoints
FROM Rewards r JOIN
     MaxRewards mr
     ON r.CustomerID = mr.CustomerID
```

This can also be expressed as a lateral join, using `cross apply`.

This assumes that `DateReceived` does not have duplicates.  If that is possible, then this is subtly different.

Also note that the performance is likely to be much worse than using window functions, but an index on `rewards(customerid, datereceived, point)` would help.